# Javascript (Syntax Error: Illegal Character ) on Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, renderpartial

In my view, I'm rendering a table as a partial view (Ruby on Rails) using ajax:

```
j.ajax({
  type: 'POST' ,
  url: '<%=  url_for :action => "distribute_payments" %>',
  data : {
    'no_payments' :n,
    'total_payment' :t,
    'id' :id,
  },
  beforeSend : function() {
  },
  success : function() {
    j("#payments_distribute").html(data);
  }
});
```

This is working great:

[image: This is the view I want to show]

But now I need to run the following javascript in my partial view:

```
  function payment_sum() {
    var precision = parseInt("<%= @precision %>");
    var sum = 0;
    j('.payment_box').each(function () {
      sum += +parseFloat(this.value) || 0
    });

    return sum.toFixed(precision);
  }

  function submit(){
    alert ('I am here');
    var total = "<%= @total_payment %>";
    var n= "<%@no_payments%>";
    if (payment_sum()!= total){

      alert('<%=t('cant_pay_more')%>');
      j('.payment_box').each(function () {
      this.value= total/n });

      return false;
    } 
    else
      return true;

}
```

But when I click on the button, the javascript code doesn't run. So I opened inspect element and found this error:

```
ReferenceError: data is not defined


j("#payments_distribute").html(data);
```

And I fixed it here:

```
j.ajax({
  type: 'POST' ,
  url: '<%=  url_for :action => "distribute_payments" %>',
  data : {
    'no_payments' :n,
    'total_payment' :t,
    'id' :id,
  },
  beforeSend : function() {
  },
  success : function(data) {
    j("#payments_distribute").html(data);
  }
});
  }
```

But this is the result:

[image]

And I have this error:

```
SyntaxError: illegal character


\r\n    \r\n  function payment_sum() {\r\n    var precision
```

And when I click on save I get an error, because that's how my parameters are returned:

```
Parameters: {"\\\"payments"=>{"1"=>{"title"=>{"\\\""=>"\\\"Second"}, "date"=>{"\\\""=>"\\\"2015-11-12\\\""}, "amount"=>{"\\\""=>"\\\"1600000.00\\\""}}, "0"=>{"title"=>{"\\\""=>"\\\"First"}, "date"=>{"\\\""=>"\\\"2015-10-12\\\""}, "amount"=>{"\\\""=>"\\\"1600000.00\\\""}}}, "\\\"authenticity_token\\\""=>"\\\"30wp5EYedFmam9BQR8f9Qu2rn/rWCx0HNW0WT968C1o=\\\"", "\\\"\\\""=>"\\\"12"}

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/parent_wise_fee_payments/manage_payments/\\\"/parent_wise_fee_payments/manage_payments/10" with {:domain=>"acme.local", :subdomain=>"acmeschool", :method=>:get, :host=>"acmeschool.acme.local"}):
```

I can't figure out what's the error here, and why when the argument "data" in my success function was missing I still got the result I needed, without being able to run another javascript function? could you please help me with this?

Comment: What's the browser's console output if you replace your `success` by : `success : function(data) { console.log(data);
    j("#payments_distribute").html(data);
  }`

Comment: This is the output: SyntaxError: illegal character \"submit()"\

Comment: I think it is a problem of Json encoding, you have a malformed json server-side

Comment: Try to proceed by steps; remove the function content and try adding more and more by step ! start with `function payment_sum() {};function submit(){};` you will be able to detect the problem